# Why are where clauses only valid on functions with generic parameters?

Tags: swift, generics

It seems absurd that this method signature does not compile in Swift 4:

```
class Bar<ValueType> { 
    func version() throws -> String where ValueType == [String: Any] { ... }
}
```

(Error: where clause cannot be attached to a non-generic declaration)
but this compiles fine:

```
class Bar<ValueType> { 
   func version<T>(_ foo: T? = nil) throws -> String where ValueType == [String: Any] { ... }  
}
```

Anyone have insight as to why this is the case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `ValueType` has nothing to do with this method (in the first example). It would be wrong to put such a method in a type (`class`/`struct`/`enum`), since it's not really a true member of that type. It's conditionally a member of that type, depending on the truth value of the `where` clause.

To achieve this, you would want to put this method in an extension of your type, with the `where` clause you want. E.g.

```
extension YourType where ValueType == [String: Any] {
    func version() throws -> String { ... }
}
```

Comment: Is the restriction on using the where clause intended to enforce best practices, rather than being a compiler limitation?

Comment: @SidMani No, it's just a consequence of what it means for a function to be found inside the declaring body of a type. It means that function is a method that exists on type. What you have is not a method that exists on the type. You have a method can *might* exist on the type.

Comment: @SidMani the rules could be made such that this were possible, but it would be a total shit show. For every single method you see, you have to check the associated `where` clause to see if the method is applicable. This could be the case for a great number of methods, which all share the same where clause. That's very cluttering, and needlessly complex

Comment: So if I understand correctly, constraints on types unrelated to the method signature such as ValueType are allowed on generic methods because the where clause has to be checked anway?

Comment: @SidMani not sure what you mean by "because the where clause has to be checked anyway", but yeah. Clauses purely relating to conditions of the type and its type parameter go in the where clause of the extension. Within the where clauses of the functions, only conditions relating to that function's  parameters and return type, the relations amongst them

Answer (score 2):

That has been finally allowed in **Swift 5.3**. See [Contextual Where Clauses](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Generics.html#ID628) in the official Language Guide.

Citing from there:

> You can write a generic `where` clause as part of a declaration that doesn’t have its own generic type constraints, when you’re already working in the context of generic types. For example, you can write a generic `where` clause on a subscript of a generic type or on a method in an extension to a generic type.
>
> ...
>
> ```swift
> extension Container {
>     func average() -> Double where Item == Int {
>         var sum = 0.0
>         for index in 0..<count {
>             sum += Double(self[index])
>         }
>         return sum / Double(count)
>     }
> ```

That compiles just fine in Xcode 12 beta 4, but won't work in Xcode 11.6 that is shipped with Swift 5.2.4.